# Scala: Can't get outer class members from inner class reference

Tags: scala, inner-classes

I can't seem to get the outer class members from an inner class reference:

```
class Outer(st: Int)
{
  val valOut = st
  def f = 4
  class Inner { val x = 5 }
}

object myObj {
val myOut = new Outer(8)
val myIn = new myOut.Inner
val myVal: Int = myIn.valOut//value f is not a member of ... myOut.Inner
val x = myIn.f//value valOut is not a member of ... myOut.Inner
}
```

I've tried this inside packages and in the eclipse worksheet neither works. I'm using Scala 2.10.0RC1 in eclipse 3.7.2 with Scala plug-in 2.1.0M2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why you expect this to compile. After all, `Inner` does not have those members, only its enclosing class has them. You can achieve what you want this way:

```
class Outer(st: Int) {
  val valOut = st
  def f = 4
  class Inner {
    val outer = Outer.this
    val x = 5
  }
}

object myObj {
  val myOut = new Outer(8)
  val myIn = new myOut.Inner
  val myVal: Int = myIn.outer.valOut
  val x = myIn.outer.f
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that Outer.this is a useful trick I didn't know. I thought I needed to create a self type in the outer class and then reference the self type to do it that way. I'm sure that Classname.this could be useful in other places not just inner types. I expected my code to compile because an inner class already holds a reference to the outer class, which you can use automatically when writing code inside the inner class. So this does seem like a waste of bytes and requires boilerplate.

Comment: It is not a waste of bytes, since you might not want members of the outer class to leak into the API of the inner class.

Comment: It still seems like a wasteful use of bytes. The outer inherent reference would be public by default under my assumption while in reality its something like protected[this]. Surely the logical solution would be to give a way to change the access modifiers of the inherent outer reference not to force the creation of a duplicate field if one wants to change the access.

Comment: If you look at the output of `javap -v`, you'll notice that no second field is created for `outer`, just a method, so no bytes are wasted per instance of `Inner`.

Comment: That's good to know, and hopefully the method call gets in-lined.

Comment: Inlining is done by the JVM, not by the compiler. Whether it is done is determined at runtime.